# How to format (print) output of the shell-command function

Tags: format

I have this

```
(defun insert-dateutc ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "printf %s $(date +\"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\")" t))
```

which I want to use in this

```
(defun foo1 ()
  (format "this is the date-time %s" (insert-dateutc)))
```

but the output is the elisp id number of the function call (yes?)

```
(foo1)
==> "this is the date-time 1185"
2015-11-18T20:31:30 ; <-- inserted
```

with the actual desired return left outside. I need to suppress that number and get the actual date-time output. Gosh, I know it's something simple...

Comment: Is your question really about getting something from the shell process, to use in Emacs, or is it just about being able to display or return or insert a timestamp string in Emacs? If the latter, just use `current-time-string` or use `current-time` with `format-time-string`.

Comment: I want to use the output of that shell-command in the first function, i.e., not just any timestamp. Obviously I could just put the `(shell-command ...)` part in `foo1`, but it does the same thing AFAIK.

Comment: You can use `call-process` or `start-process`, to get more control. Otherwise, the `shell-command` call you are using puts the output of the `printf` command in the current buffer, at point. You could wrap the call in `with-current-buffer-window` or similar (in which case you don't need the second arg), to recuperate the output.

Comment: `(defun foo1 ()
  (format "this is the date-time %S" (shell-command "date +\"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\"" t)))` is without the `printf`, but with the same bad results. The `printf` was only to avoid a newline. What exactly should I do with `call-process`?

Comment: . . . of course if I can get ISO 8601 format of UTC out of `format-time-string` I'm home free. . .

Comment: your code worked fine for me, although it seems a little odd to me that you have not made `foo1` interactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is just a timestamp, you can use

```
(defvar user-time-format
  (eval-when-compile (or (getenv "STRFTIME") "%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S %Z"))
  "The time format for the user to set.")
(defun user-time-format (&optional insert)
  "Return or insert the time string according to `user-time-format'."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((str (format-time-string user-time-format)))
    (if insert (insert str)
        (if (called-interactively-p 'interactive) (message "%s" str) str))))
```

except you would set `user-time-format` to `"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S"`.

However, your question raises an interesting issue, so let us discuss it too.

Your `insert-dateutc` is fine (but see below), but it *inserts* the date instead of returning it,
so  `foo` has to correct that:

```
(defun foo ()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-dateutc)
    (buffer-string)))

(format "timestamp = [%s]" (foo))
==> "timestamp = [2015-11-18T16:37:12]"
```

Finally, take a look at <kbd>C-h f shell-command RET</kbd>. It says discourages the use of this function in lisp code, recommending `call-process` instead:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (call-process "date" nil t nil "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
  (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (line-end-position 0)))
==> "2015-11-18T16:47:27"
```

Comment: Your `foo` (with the `format` bundled inside a cl-flet) works fine -- in my *scratch*, but when I call it in my org buffer . . . nothing appears. Apparently the `format` form doesn't "print"?

Comment: `format` converts its arguments to a string. you might want to pass it to `insert` which will insert the string into the buffer or use `message` instead of `format` to report the text in the echo area.